# Drawable assets blown up on HTC DNA

Tags: android, android-drawable, screen-resolution

I ran my app on the htc dna. I observed that my icons in the action bar are HUGE and don't even fit on it. I had 3 buckets for my drawables : mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi. I tried creating a xxhdpi bucket and copied my xhdpi assets to it. Still they blow up.
What should I be doing to get the assets right?

**Update: added photos**

Nexus 4:

[image: On Nexus 4]

HTC DNA :
[image: On HTC DNA]

If it helps I have generated the drawables from the Android asset tool (http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)

Comment: Pretty sure Android doesn't recognize a xxhdpi folder, or does it? Anyways, have you tested your xhdpi drawables on any other devices that use that bucket?

Comment: Yes, they (xhdpi) work on my Nexus 4

Comment: Weird... Can you post a picture of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out: The icons I had generated were too big (some 344x344px). However, funny thing is Android scaled these well from the xhdpi bucket on xhdpi phones (nexus 4). However, when I copied them over to xxhdpi bucket they were getting picked (on 1080p devices - htc dna) and blown up. I resized the icons from xxhdpi bucket to around 150x150px  Now they fix on the action bar and look better.